# Solved: Spark make nonunique fields have an ID by order of occurance

Tags: sql, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a bunch of CSV Files that i read in to spark (working with pyspark) and after i want to join them on a specific field to one big table.

The problem is, this field is not unique, but the attributes associated are. It was unique where the data comes from, but this information got dropped before i get them as csv. I cannot state the connection between the files using additive attributes for my join query. But the order of appearance in all files kind of states the structure.
So if i could make an artificial ID having the ID and the number of appearance in the file it will work.

My Question is, can i define an SparkSQL Query (or another pyspark way) with which i add an consecutive count for the nonunique rows in each file, so i can use that for my join?

What i want is:

```
ID| ct(ID) | generated_number
A | 2      | 1 
A | 2      | 2
A | 2      | 3
B | 1      | 1
C | 2      | 1
C | 2      | 2
D | 1      | 1
E | 3      | 1
E | 3      | 2
E | 3      | 3
```

based on that i could create a new ID as conc(ID, '_', generated_number) - at least i would do for the rows with nonunique.

Is there a clever SparkNative Version, i really don't want to modify the source data in a shell script (awk i would think of)

Thanks a lot

SOLUTION:

Both answers fit the solution, thanks alot. My approach now is as follows:

```
SELECT  ID,
   row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY ID
        ORDER BY ID ) as row_count,
   count(ID) OVER (
        PARTITION BY ID
         ORDER BY ID ) as count
FROM TB_TEMP AS main
WHERE cellname_s = "A"
```

Well not using the WHERE clause, but for showing it makes it easier ;)

Which gives me the desired output:

```
+----------+---------+-----+
|        ID|row_count|count|
+----------+---------+-----+
|         A|        1|    4|
|         A|        2|    4|
|         A|        3|    4|
|         A|        4|    4|
+----------+---------+-----+
```

To get my unique ID i will make an

```
CASE WHEN count > 1 THEN concact(ID, "_", row_count) ELSE ID END AS ID
```

Thus giving me unique fields where i don't have but not manipulating the fields that are unique already as is better for the people working with the data.

Comment: did you try out the solutions below? can you mark any one of them as the accepted answer?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the help so far! I will try tomorrow when im working again and post details here of what helped (and mark accepted answer). Sorry for delay but the weekend im off

Comment: No issue.. good luck:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking for a row_number here

use something like

```
 select id,CT(id),row_number() over(partition by id,CT(id) order  by id) from ** your ** table
```

and if you want it in Dataframe You can uSe:

```
https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html
```

Comment: The problem here is for each occurance like [A 1] the id must change. In this approach all the A will be continuously numbered

Comment: select id,CT(id),row_number() over(partition by id,CT(id) order  by id) from ** your ** table

Comment: this works. Like that the same column can be used also for partition and ordering

Answer (score 1):

The catch is the non unique values. You can use the monotonically_increasing_id() function.

```
tst=sqlContext.createDataFrame([('A',2),('B',2),('A',2),('A',3),('B',4),('A',2),('B',2)],schema=("id","count"))
tst_id = tst.withColumn("inc_id",monotonically_increasing_id())
```

This will make sure that unique ids are assigned for the non unique values. For your case you can also use this to concatenate with the id. But if you want consecutive and better looking id numbers, then we can use a row number over this generated monotonically increasing id(costly in performance wise):

```
w=Window.partitionBy('id','count').orderBy('inc_id')
tst_row = tst_id.withColumn("uniq_id",F.row_number().over(w))
```

so, finally

```
tst_row.sort('id','count','uniq_id').show()
+---+-----+----------+-------+
| id|count|    inc_id|uniq_id|
+---+-----+----------+-------+
|  A|    2|         0|      1|
|  A|    2|         2|      2|
|  A|    2|8589934594|      3|
|  A|    3|8589934592|      1|
|  B|    2|         1|      1|
|  B|    2|8589934595|      2|
|  B|    4|8589934593|      1|
+---+-----+----------+-------+
```